# Fragment data is lost when multiple time startActivityForResult is called

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have written the following code to set the String of fragment. By using startActivityForResult I am getting the value and set the to fragment string i.e (firstString, secondString)

But the problem is that whenever I call startActivityForResult the fragment is recreated and the previous data is lost. For example when I set secondString than the value of firstString is lost.

I have referred to few answers to save and restore the fragment data, but unable to do so.

```
boolean isEditing = true;
LinearLayout first_layout, second_layout;
TextView first_textview, second_textview;
String firstString, secondString;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    if(savedInstanceState!=null)
    {
        if(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isEditing",false))
        {
            Log.e("onSaveInstanceState","Restored");
            isEditing=true;
            firstString = savedInstanceState.getString(firstString);
            secondString = savedInstanceState.getString(secondString);
        }
    }
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mf_postload, container, false);

    // Linearlayout
    first_layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.payment_layout_MF_PostLoad);
    second_layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.remark_layout_MF_PostLoad);

    // TextView
    first_textview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.payment_MF_PostLoad);
    second_textview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.remark_MF_PostLoad);

    first_textview.setText(firstString);
    second_textview.setText(firstString);


    // Listner
    first_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Remark.class);
            Integer requestCode = 1;
            intent.putExtra("requestCode", requestCode);
            startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
        }
    });

    second_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Remark.class);
            Integer requestCode = 2;
            intent.putExtra("requestCode", requestCode);
            startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
    Log.e("onSaveInstanceState","Called");
    try
    {
        if(isEditing)
        {
            bundle.putBoolean("isEditing",true);
            bundle.putString("firstString",firstString);
            bundle.putString("secondString",secondString);
            Log.e("onSaveInstanceState","Called and Saved");
        }
        else
        {
            bundle.putBoolean("isEditing",false);
            Log.e("onSaveInstanceState","Called and not Saved");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// Call Back method  to get the Message form other Activity
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // First
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            firstString = data.getStringExtra("remark_string");
            first_textview.setText(firstString);
        }

    }

    // Second
    if (requestCode == 2) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            secondString = data.getStringExtra("remark_string");
            second_textview.setText(secondString);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: When you are calling a new activity the old one which contains your fragment is destroyed which means your fragment is destroyed too and the reason of that is that the device needs memory resources (RAM) so its automatically destroying the background activities and the solution of that is overriding the `onSaveInstanceState` and then in `onCreate` read the saved values into their respective attribute

Comment: @Haidar can you provide me some sample code for refrence

Comment: Ok i will post an answer

Comment: did you checked my answer?

Comment: @Haidar I have edited the code in question, tried your answer but its not working, guide me if I am doing it wrong.

Comment: is `Log.e("onSaveInstanceState","Called and not Saved");` and `Log.e("onSaveInstanceState","Called and Saved");` being called?

Comment: Yes "onSaveInstanceState: Called" and "onSaveInstanceState: Called and Saved" is called but "onSaveInstanceState:Restored" is not called.

Comment: do some debugging put a break point on the sentence `if(savedInstanceState!=null)` and tell me what u see 
is  savedInstanceState==null? and if not is it empty?

Comment: what happened ?

Comment: savedInstanceState!=null and isEditing is true, but string values are null

Comment: am not sure i use this in an Activity never tried it on a Fragment 
try doing this procedure on the level of activity and not fragment

Answer (score 0):

Here is the overriding of `onSaveInstance`

```
//Like you see here am using a boolean to determine if i need to save the variable of not
//because if i am finishing the activity normally and its not the case where system kills it 
//so i dont need to save these and if case that this boolean is true than the system is
//killing my activity and i need to save the values
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);

    Log.e("onSaveInstanceState","Called");

    try
    {
        if(isEditing)
        {
            bundle.putBoolean("isEditing",true);
            bundle.putString("photoFile", photoFile.getAbsoluteFile()+"");
            bundle.putString("birthday",birthdayText.getText().toString());
            bundle.putString("phone",phoneText.getText().toString());
            bundle.putString("gender",genderText.getText().toString());
            bundle.putString("martial",martialText.getText().toString());
            bundle.putString("email",emailText.getText().toString());
            bundle.putString("first",editFirstName.getText().toString());
            bundle.putString("last",editLastName.getText().toString());
            Log.e("onSaveInstanceState","Called and Saved");
        }
        else
        {
            bundle.putBoolean("isEditing",false);
            Log.e("onSaveInstanceState","Called and not Saved");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is the overriding of `onCreate`

```
//In onCreate am checking if i need to restore these values or not according 
//to what i saved and in this way its like my activity never got killed 
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    if(savedInstanceState!=null)
    {
        if(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isEditing",false))
        {
            Log.e("onSaveInstanceState","Restored");

            isEditing=true;
            photoFile =new File(savedInstanceState.getString("photoFile"),"") ;
            birthdayText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("birthday","1/1/1980"));
            phoneText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("phone",""));
            genderText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("gender","Please specify gender"));
            martialText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("martial","Please specify marital"));
            emailText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("email",""));
            editFirstName.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("first",""));
            editLastName.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("last",""));


        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging I have solved, Thanks Haider.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
    Log.e("onSaveInstanceState", "Called");
    bundle.putString("firstString", firstString);
    bundle.putString("secondString", secondString);
    Log.e("onSaveInstanceState", "Called and Saved" + firstString + " " + secondString);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.e("onSaveInstanceState", "Restored Called");
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        firstString = savedInstanceState.getString("firstString");
        secondString = savedInstanceState.getString("secondString");
        Log.e("onSaveInstanceState", "Restored" + firstString + " " + secondString);
    }
}
```